# Convert String to macAddress Formate in java

Tags: java, string

I want to know the simplest way to convert the string "00155D038D01" to macAdress format in Java.

Comment: What do you mean by mac address format? `00:15:5D:03:8D:01`, `00-15-5D-03-8D-01` or maybe something else?

Comment: This is a statement not a question. Please read the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Exactly i need my string to be formatted like that 00-15-5D-03-8D-01..

Answer (score 12):

try with regex

```
char divisionChar = ':';//change to '-' if you want your mac to be like 00-15-5D-03-8D-01
String unformattedMAC = "00155D038D01";
String formattedMAC = unformattedMAC.replaceAll("(.{2})", "$1"+divisionChar).substring(0,17);
```

works with all MAC addresses you have

Comment: You can be more specific : replace ".{2}" with "[0-9A-F]{2}"

Answer (score 8):

I would say that `"00155D038D01".replaceAll("(..)(?!$)", "$1-")` is the simplest :)

Comment: +1 Better than harlandraka's answer.

Comment: Unbelievably Simple and Functional... Envy your mind!

Answer (score 7):

Obviously,

```
public String convertToMacAddress(String input) {
   if (input.equals("00155D038D01") {
       return "00-15-5D-03-8D-01";
   } 

   return null; 
}
```

Comment: +1 This is indeed the simplest way

Comment: Simple, but it's not a conversion

Comment: +1 Definitely what the OP asked for :)

Comment: Thanks @thai for your reply but i need general solution for string..So that i can convert any string to machAdress as suggested by above ...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward way:

```
String s = "00155D038D01";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < s.length();)
{
    sb.append(s.substring(i++, ++i));
    if(i < s.length()) sb.append("-");
}
String mac = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String address = "00155D038D01";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(address);

for(int i = 2; i < address.length()+(i/3); i+=3){
   sb.insert(i, ':');
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```