# Need to convert a string "4AAC6AA8D5827BA" to into this format "4a:ac:6a:a8:d5:82:7b" using groovy

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I am trying to convert this string  string  "4AAC6AA8D5827BA" to into this format  "4a:ac:6a:a8:d5:82:7b" using groovy. Could you please asssit

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559878/convert-string-to-macaddress-formate-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def addDots(x) { x.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/([0-9a-f]{2})(?!$)/, '$0:') }
```

This doesn't check that the input is of the correct pattern and will do weird things to anything in a different format.

But `addDots("4AAC6AA8D5827BA")` will return `4a:ac:6a:a8:d5:82:7b:a`

Note that the input you gave has an odd number of characters, which is probably a copy-paste error somewhere.

Comment: this worked . Yes it is a copy paste error . I am trying to 4AAC6AA8D5827BAD0000000054D021DF which gave me an output as 4a:ac:6a:a8:d5:82:7b:ad:00:00:00:00:54:d0:21:df

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you want to ommit the last "A", but the code would do it:

```
String res = "4AAC6AA8D5827BA".toLowerCase().toList().collate( 2 ).findResults{ 2 == it.size() ? it.join( '' ) : null }.join( ':' )
assert res == '4a:ac:6a:a8:d5:82:7b'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def addDots(x) { x.toLowerCase().findAll(/..?/).join(':') }
```